# Truly accept unlimited arguments from file in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm looking for a way to truly process an unlimited number of arguments from a file in bash. The problem I'm having is xargs quits after 14881 lines. My files are 1.9gb and contain roughly 30m lines. Is there a better way I should be doing this?

My Code Sample:

```
cat /home/user/Desktop/file.log | xargs ethereum_private_key_to_address
```

This works wonderfully but quits after said amount of lines on 35 different instances.

edit:
To be clear, i need to process this file line by line. Each line is exactly 64 characters, no spaces a-f and 0-9

edit: 
Went with python, been running all night 3m+ lines written, i think its firmly stable.

```
import subprocess
filepath = '/home/linadmin/Desktop/pkeys.log'
with open(filepath) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   while line:
       line = fp.readline()

       convertaddress = subprocess.run(["ethereum_private_key_to_address"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, input=line)
       f = open("/home/linadmin/Desktop/processed.log", "a")
       f.write(convertaddress.stdout)
       f.close()
```

Comment: There is no limit on the number of lines `xargs` will process. You should instead determine why `xargs` is quitting early. For example, does the file contain a stray quote or a single line over 128k? Does the command at any point exit with 255 or get killed by a signal?

Comment: @will.ditch: What do you mean by "it quits"? If it stops early, you should get an error message at least. What is the exit status of xargs after quitting?

Comment: @will.ditch : Also, you might try to run `xargs` with `--verbose`. Since the output will be pretty large in your case, I suggest to redirect it to a file. Note that the _verbose_ option writes its log to stderr!

Comment: Does `ethereum_private_key_to_address` accept more than one argument?

Comment: @rici no, proper syntax is command and then 16bit 64char hex string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that `xargs` quits after reading 14881 lines. It reads the entire input, and divides it into what it believes are the longest possible command lines based on its conservative estimate of the maximum size of a command. (See `getconf ARG_MAX`).

This assumes that the target command can take an arbitrary number of arguments and acts on all of them. Many standard command line utilities work exactly in this way. And there is an important efficiency which results, because loading and initialising an executable is a significant overhead. In your case, `xargs` divided the 30 million arguments provided from your log file into 14,881 invocations of `ethereum_private_key_to_address`, giving each invocation about 2,000 arguments.

The problem is that `ethereum_private_key_to_address` ignores all but its first argument. So only 14,881 keys were actually processed. These are not the first 14,881 lines, but rather 14,881 lines equally spaced on your input file.

The best solution is to rewrite the utility to understand multiple arguments. But if you cannot do that, you can use the `-n1` command-line option to tell `xargs` to put a maximum of one argument on each command line.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you so kindly for taking the time to explain so eloquently.

Answer (score -1):

Why not pass input via `stdin`

```
ethereum_private_key_to_address  "$(</home/user/Desktop/file.log)"
```

Comment: This tries to pass the entire file as a single argument

Comment: What is the content of your file?   Try `"$(tr '\n' '  ' </home/user/Desktop/file.log)" `

Comment: This would also try to pass the entire file in a single argument. If you want to pass the contents on stdin, you would need to use `ethereum_private_key_to_address  < file.log` but obviously this will not work unless the command is written to accept data on stdin.

Comment: OP wants to pass the entire file in single line only. Not row by row processing.

Comment: That would be unquoted `ethereum_private_key_to_address $(</home/user/Desktop/file.log)`, but 1.9GB is likely too much data to pass via arguments in one go

Comment: each line is exactly 64 characters a-f and 0-9